# Pretty URL Mapping with Spring 3.0

Tags: controller, spring-3

I'm getting the following error when trying to map a URL path called "new" to a Controller method which does some logic, then displays the view "index.jsp":

> WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/springguestbook/index.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springguestbook'

This is my Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showGuestbookEntries(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    this.guestbookService = GuestbookService.getInstance(session);
    model.addAttribute("guestbookEntries",
            guestbookService.getGuestbookEntries());

    return "index";

}
```

These are the contents of my web.xml file:

```
<display-name>Spring Guestbook</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springguestbook</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springguestbook</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And this is the configuration of my ViewResolver:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
```

It seems to me that instead of actually reading the contents of index.jsp and displaying them,  the method just redirects to index.jsp instead.
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. Try changing your servlet mapping to this (change `/*` to `/`):

   ```
   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>springguestbook</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   ```
2. Make sure you're using a view resolver that can find your JSP, like `InternalResourceViewResolver`:

   ```
   @Bean
   public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
       InternalResourceViewResolver b = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
       b.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
       b.setSuffix(".jsp");
       return b;
   }
   ```

or

```
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: I don't mean to be greedy, but do you mind giving my answer an up-vote?