# Servlet mapping issue with SpringMVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

i'm developing a J2EE App using Spring (mvc, security, etc...) and i have a problem with the mappings. I would like to redirect people who type "..../myapp" to a welcome jsp, specifically to "/myapp/welcome.html"

Previously my servlet-mapping had this config:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>MyApp</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But i changed it, in order to catch the "/myapp" request. The newone that i wrote is the following:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>ThreddsAdminPanel</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

It works as expected but when i try to access to a page which needs an css, this error appears:
"No mapping found for HTTP request with URI"

I think that if My url-pattern is /*, the servlet is catching something that doesn't belong to it although i don't know how to do it. Does anybody know a good way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

See this: [Pretty URL Mapping with Spring 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031513/pretty-url-mapping-with-spring-3-0/17031713#17031713)

Basically, change your servlet-mapping from `/*` to `/` and then you can worry about performing the redirect.

For the redirect, you should be able to do something like this (assuming use of the mvc namespace in XML config):

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/myapp" view-name="redirect:/myapp/welcome.html"/>
```

Comment: FYI, if you don't already have it, add this to your XML to use the mvc namespace: `xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"` and `xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd"`

Comment: Thank you for answering @superEb but my problem persists... i've replaced /* by / but the css and js files don't load. For example, "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myapp/js/usersTable.js]" and into the deployed folder i can see the js folder in the root as expected.

Comment: If your static resources are deployed within your web app (i.e. WAR), then you'll also need to map those resources in Spring configuration, like `<mvc:resources mapping="/myapp/js/**" location="/resources/js/" />`

Comment: Yes, my resources are deployed within the war. The <mvc:resources and <mvc:view-controller that you mentioned before must be in the web.xml file?

Comment: No, in your Spring config for the servlet, e.g. "dispatcher-servlet.xml" if your servlet name is "dispatcher", or "ThreddsAdminPanel-servlet.xml" if your servlet name is "ThreddsAdminPanel". You said you're using Spring MVC, so I assume you are using Spring's `DispatcherServlet` for your servlet class in web.xml.

Comment: i cleaned the tomcat work directory and i tried "<mvc:resources mapping="/ThreddsAdminPanel/js/**" location="/"/>" with no success. The folders are children of webapp. webapp/js, webapp/ext.. these folders are in the root, so that, i think that location is "/" but it seems like the servlet is still getting the request